# Mouse not working correctly on OS X inside VMware Player during a Windows Remote Desktop session

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop, vmware-player

At work I have a VMWare image of OS X El Capitan that I'm running in VMWare Player 12 on Windows 7.

This works perfectly, but when I access this Windows computer from home using a Remote Desktop session, the mouse inside the VMWare Player behaves very strange. The cursor is jumping all over the place (or simply is way too fast).

Already tried changing the mouse speed, tried to use Mouse Keys, installed VMWare Tools, but nothing worked. Is there any setting that I'm missing ?
And is this a OS X or VMWare Player or Windows 7 issue ?  (the mouse works just fine outside the VMWare Player window)

Answer (score 0):

Finally gave up on using VMWare Player in Remote Desktop. It just doesn't work well.

I installed [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com) on both the OS X image and my Windows computer at home.
Then I made sure the OS X image was on the same subnet as the network at work, (using Bridged mode in network settings in VMWare Player) and defined a fixed IP in OS X. Then I forwarded port 4000 in my router to this IP, so I could use NoMachine from my Windows computer at home directly to the OS X image at work. Works like a breeze.